# data augmentation in multimodal classification

Tags: classification

I am working on a multimodal classification task in which Image-Text is inputted in pairs. The number of train data in each label is different, so I'm trying to solve it by augmenting the data.
Is there a python library or code snippet available in this situation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.